# Magento search not working during reindexing?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, reindex

I am using an import script to import all my products from a custom file and after each import I reindex all the indices like this:

```
try {

    // @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection
    $indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
    foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
        // @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process
        $index->reindexAll();
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    Mage::log('Import: Reindex failed.');
}
```

but during this process the magento search is not working and returns that products could not be found. Is this the default behaviour of magento or can I fix this?

I synchronize my products many times each day so it is not so great, if the search is not working at this time. Hope you can help me :).

Comment: i think you have to refer this http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/103037/45103

Comment: the solution of the suggested article is reindexing via cronjob, but in my case I thought the reindex process after an import is causing the problem, anyway I have removed the reindexing code from my import script and I have created a new script for reindexing which will only be fired second times each day by a cronjob

Comment: Yes exactly I want to direct you in that way only. Once in a day reindexing is more optimal than every time