# How can I set up CRON to automatically re-ndex each night

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, search, indexing

We have an issue on our website where the search functionality periodically stops working.  I'm not sure why but when we re-index * Catalog Search Index* & *Category Products* it works again.

One solution we would like to use is to re-index these each night.  At them moment we have this in our crontab.

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/magento-root/cron.sh
30 4 * * * /var/www/magento-root/rediscli.php -s 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -d 1
```

Do I just need add the following to it:

```
30 2 * * * php -q /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product,catalogsearch_fulltext
```

I'm not too familiar with CRONTABS

Comment: which hosting provider are you using

Comment: we're using a AWS EC2 instance on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Your cron expression is correct, `30 2 * * *` will run every day at 2:30am.

I'd make some amendments to the crontab you've put and have it as follows:

```
30 2 * * * ! test -e /path/to/magento/maintenance.flag && php -q /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product,catalogsearch_fulltext >> /path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log;
```

**Explanation:**

```
30 2 * * * ! test -e /path/to/magento/maintenance.flag &&
```

Will test for the maintenance flag and will stop the script from running if it's enabled (Good practise to have this on all crons you have defined)

```
php -q /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product,catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Run the script via PHP.

```
>> /path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log;
```

Echo the output of the script to the cron.log file, helps to ensure it is running correctly.

I tend to use: https://crontab.guru/ if I need to make references to any crontab expressions.